# Is there a way to get the equivalent of hg merge --preview with hg log and revsets?

Tags: mercurial

I like being able to see what changes will come in on a merge with `hg merge --preview` but sometimes I wish I could change the formatting a bit, or show only commits that affect certain files, or commits made by certain people.  There appears to be no way to specify a different log output format or to apply any filters when using `hg merge --preview` so I wonder if I can somehow get the same list of changesets using `hg log` and revsets.  If I had that I'm pretty sure I could figure out how to tweak it how I like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want all ancestors of the changeset you are merging with, excluding common ones with the parent of your working directory:

> $ hg log -r "ancestors(mergerev) - ancestors(.)"

or in short form:

> $ hg log -r "::mergerev - ::."

see hg help [revsets](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets) for more.

Comment: Yup, that produces exactly the same output as hg merge --preview.  Thanks!!